# multi query and pagination with firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement multi query and pagination with firestore, but once I add < or > to the query the cursor not working.

```js
//working example:
the doc id i save as propery on the doc
ref.where('category','==' 'cats').where('status', '==', 1).orderBy('id').cursor('last doc id from the returned list').limit(3)

//not working exmple:

ref.where('category','==' 'cats').where('status', '==', 1).orderBy('price').where('price', '>=', 2).where('price', '<=', 55).orderBy('id').cursor('last doc id from the returned list').limit(3)
```

no error returned. is it bug with firestore or on my end.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There has documentation at firebase on [Pagination & Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) and [query data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data). We have to use the **startAt()** or **startAfter()** methods to define the start point for a query. Similarly, use the **endAt()** or **endBefore()** methods to define an end point for your query results.

Example:
To get all cities with a population >= 1,000,000, ordered by population,

```
db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .startAt(1000000);
```

and to get all cities with a population <= 1,000,000, ordered by population,

```
db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .endAt(1000000);
```

**So pagination should be done using this method like,**

```
// Construct query for first 25 cities, ordered by population
Query first = db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .limit(25);

first.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
            // ...

            // Get the last visible document
            DocumentSnapshot lastVisible = documentSnapshots.getDocuments()
                    .get(documentSnapshots.size() -1);

            // Construct a new query starting at this document,
            // get the next 25 cities.
            Query next = db.collection("cities")
                    .orderBy("population")
                    .startAfter(lastVisible)
                    .limit(25);

            // Use the query for pagination
            // ...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

A Firestore query can only have a single range condition.

From the [documentation on queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data):

> You can combine `where()` filters with `orderBy()` and `limit()`.
>
> However, if you have a filter with a range comparison (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`), your first ordering must be on the same field:
>
> **Invalid**: Range filter and first orderBy on different fields
>
> ```
> citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("country")
> ```

Comment: so i cant combine range comparison (<, <=, >, >=) with startAfter on different property?
is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 4):

**Check [this](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-8-firestore-show-firestore-data-with-next-previous-pagination-in-tabular-form/) example App using FireStore with Angular 8 app having pagination**

[image]

using queries

**limit()**

**orderBy()**

**startAt()**

**endBefore()**

**startAfter()**

Answer (score 1):

As Frank pointed out so far firestore doesn't permit combining ranges on different properties. I hope google will fix this someday, having multiple range filters seems like a pretty essential feature for any database.

Also it's a rather ugly solution, but I guess you could leave out the `.where('price', '>=', 2)` part and filter out the data afterwards on the client.

Comment: thanks man you gave me idea. i will change it from range to bigger than. i guess its better than nothing. i really don't understand why they don't implement all those features like mongo. its really hard to work with it.

Comment: @shimonhatoka they will properly do this in the future... They added alot new features since I began using it last year :)