# Order by a number field where a timestamp is on a given date in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

In my Firestore database I have some documents in a collection that look like this:

```
{
  name: "Item 1",
  count: 2,
  timestamp: January 29, 2018 at 3:43:12 PM UTC-8
}
```

I'm trying to query this collection such that the documents are ordered by `count` in descending order, AND have their `timestamp`'s date equal to today's date.

Using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), this is the query I have so far:

```
const startOfToday = moment().startOf('day').toDate();
const endOfToday = moment().endOf('day').toDate();

const query = db.collection('items')
                .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
                .orderBy('count', 'desc')
                .where('timestamp', '>=', startOfToday)
                .where('timestamp', '<=', endOfToday);
```

And this query does indeed fetch the records that have today as their `timestamp`'s date, however it appears to be ordering them by `timestamp` first, and if two had the same `timestamp`, it would then order by `count`.

The obvious solution would be to switch the order of the `orderBy` functions so it would order by `count` then `timestamp`, but when I tried doing this Firestore threw the following error:

> FirebaseError: Invalid query. You have a where filter with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) on field 'timestamp' and so you must also use 'timestamp' as your first Query.orderBy(), but your first Query.orderBy() is on field 'count' instead.

If anyone has any ideas, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: As far as I know it isn't possible to combine range filters on one field with an `orderBy` on another field. See my and Dan's answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46792275). You'll have to use the query to filter the data and then re-order it client-side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multi query and pagination with firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782789/multi-query-and-pagination-with-firestore)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Cloud Firestore does not support using more than a single field in range filters and/or order by clauses.

Given the nature of your query though, it is relatively simple to change it to an equality filter (today's date) and order by clause (count). You'll need to store a separate field, let's call it `date`, that just contains the date (e.g. `2018/01/30`) and not the time. You'll then be able to query as:

```
const query = db.collection('items')
                .orderBy('count', 'desc')
                .where('date', '==', today);
```