# Firestore pagination of multiple queries

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In my case, there are 10 fields and all of them need to be searched by `"or"`, that is why I'm using multiple queries and filter common items in client side by using `Promise.all()`.

The problem is that I would like to implement pagination. I don't want to get all the results of each query, which has too much "read" cost. But I can't use `.limit()` for each query cause what I want is to limit "final result".

For example, I would like to get the first 50 common results in the 10 queries' results, if I do `limit(50)` to each query, the final result might be less than 50.

Anyone has ideas about pagination for multiple queries?

Comment: You can sequentially load the subsets until you have the right number of results.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, what I'm doing now is like what you mentioned. But the drawback is like for example, I would like to get 50 results and query 200 records every time till I get 50. If it's lucky, I will get results with few times sequential query, but sometimes it would take more than 10 times because the data's distribution is random. Anyways, it's not pretty but doable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the best way for you to achieve that is using query cursors, so you can better manage the data that you retrieve from your searches.

I would recommend you to take a look at the below links, to find out more information - including a question answered by the community, that seems similar to your case.

- [Paginate data with query cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)
- [multi query and pagination with
  firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782789/multi-query-and-pagination-with-firestore)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The cursors can help. But the links you gave don't match my case very well. In my case, there are 10 separated queries. After they return results, I would do a local filter to get the common results bwtween them, if the common results don't reach the number I need, I would continue to go to the next subset till I get the right number of results. But because of data's distribution, the "time" and "read" cost can't be controlled.

Comment: Hi @yuehengshi sure, I understand. I found some additional links that might help you, otherwise, maybe continuing to use the subsets, will be your best option. The links are these one: [here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/1469) and [here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/pagination-in-flutter-with-firebase-firestore-96d6cc11aef2)

Comment: @ gso_gabriel  Thanks for the links. I think I still need to continue to use the subsets.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's relevant but I think I'm having a similar problem and have come up with 4 approaches that might be a workaround.

1. Instead of making 10 queries, fetch all the products matching a single selection filter e.g. category (in my case a customer can only set a single category field). And do all the filtering on the client side. With this approach the app still reads lots of documents at once but at least reuse these during the session time and filter with more flexibility than firestore`s strict rules.
2. Run multiple queries in a server environment, such as cloud store functions with Node.js and get only the first 50 documents that are matching all the filters. With this approach client only receives wanted data not more, but server still reads a lot.
3. **This is actually your approach combined with accepted answer**
4. Create automated documents in firebase with the help of cloud functions, e.g. Colors: {red:[product1ID,product2ID....], ....} just storing the document IDs and depending on filters get corresponding documents in server side with cloud functions, create a cross product of matching arrays (AND logic) and push first 50 elements of it to the client side. Knowing which products to display client then handle fetching client side library.

Hope these would help. Here is my original post [Firestore multiple `in` queries with `and` logic, query structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66207798/firestore-multiple-in-queries-with-and-logic-query-structure)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think the last one would be a good try for me, creating some indexes will be helpful when querying.