# Firestore multiple `in` queries with `and` logic, query structure

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I`m developing a react e-commerce app with firestore database where a customer should be able to filter multiple colors (with OR logic) AND  multiple styles (with OR logic) AND multiple brands (with OR logic) etc. and retrieve first 50 products matching these filters.

The main constraint here is that although chaining multiple equalities by using `.where("category", "==", "T-Shirts").where("color", "==", "Red")` is possible, firestore queries (client or server) does allow only single "in" type of queries. That means if a user wants to see black or red products of A and B brands a query like `.where('color', 'in', ['Red', 'Black']).where('brand', 'in', ['A', 'B'])` is not possible. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations &  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations_2 for more details.

To overcome this Firestore docs recommends using two different queries and dealing with data on the client side. However there is no mention of pagination in such use case and it means;

If there are 1000 documents in a product collection, first you have to run a query as `.where('color', 'in', ['Red', 'Black'])` get the results, let`s say 400 documents, and run another query `resultsOfFirstQuery.where('brand', 'in', ['A', 'B']).limit(50);`, this would fetch first 50 documents if there are indeed more than 50.

While this approach seems straightforward, it actually reads 400 document in order to just display 50 of them. More if a user changes single filter field this type of reading repeats again and again. To overcome this, I already thought of possible solutions;

1. Fetch all the products matching a single selection filter e.g. category (in my case a customer can only set a single category field). And do all the filtering on the client side. With this approach the app still reads lots of documents but at least reuse these during the session time.
2. Run multiple queries in a server environment, such as cloud store functions with Node.js and get only the first 50 documents that are matching all the filters. With this approach client only receives wanted data not more, but server still reads a lot.
3. Limit the queries at each step, and if there aren`t products, rerun the same queries with query cursors. E.g. `.where('color', 'in', ['Red', 'Black']).limit(50).startAfter(firstDoc)` and run `resultsOfFirstQuery.where('brand', 'in', ['A', 'B'])`, if there are 5 products rerun the query with `startAfter(lastDocLastQuery)` until you have more than 50. With this approach you still read lots of documents but you end up gradually increasing the reads 50 by 50 until you have 50 products matching.
4. Create automated documents in firebase with the help of cloud functions, e.g. `Colors: {red:[product1ID,product2ID....], ....}` and depending on filters get corresponding documents in server side with cloud functions, create a cross product of matching arrays (AND logic) and push first 50 elements of it to the client side. Knowing which products to display client then handle fetching client side library.

**Are there any other ways that I miss here, and which way do you think is the best approach considering the document reads & client side data and battery usage?**

I know that my question can be referred as opinion based, but it's really a problem, I don't want to fetch hundreds of products data each time a navigation occurs even within the same session. I need an effective way combining filtering, paginating, storing local data and could not find a way that fits the scope of my problem above.

Comment: Try to limit questions to one topic. Adding multiple questions within the question will dilute the answers and make them walls of text. Posting multiple questions is your best bet.

Comment: I will reformat the content and post the react bit as a different question, again thanks for moderation.

Comment: This depends on your data structure, this question fits better with [DBA exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option: compound values

Suppose we have three manufacturers and each has a variety of colors

```
Manufacturer A
Manufacturer B
Manufacturer C
```

and then three colors

```
Red
White
Blue
```

If we store our data in Firestore in both standard fields like manufacturer and color and then leverage a compound field, it makes doing multiple Or queries much easier

```
garment_0
   manufacturer: "Manufacturer A"
   color: "Red"
   compound: "A_R" //manufacture A, Red
garment_1
   manufacturer: "Manufacturer A"
   color: "White"
   compound: "A_W"
garment_2
   manufacturer: "Manufacturer B"
   color: "Blue"
   compound: "B_B"
garment_3
   manufacturer: "Manufacturer B"
   color: "White"
   compound: "B_W"
```

Suppose the user wants all manufacturer A and B's garments that are White or Blue

```
garmentsRef.whereField("compound", in: ["A_W", "A_B", "B_W", "B_B"])
```

Would return garment_1 ( Manufacturer A, White), garment_2 (Manufacturer B, Blue) and garment_3 (Manufacturer B, White)

Comment: Thanks, I've read about this, and it's indeed useful as these compound indexes are managable by cloud functions. However an `in` query let`s you use up to 10 values inside the array. So in a case where there are 3-4 filtering fields with 2-3 selected from each, this approach requires again multiple queries.

Comment: @MelihAlan unfortunately Firestore not support unions or joins to prevents multiple queries, most of this scenarios needs to restructure or use code workarounds to reduce the reads